# How do i make it operational? the calculator using only single digit.. in Python

Tags: python

PHYTON PROGRAMMING

How do I get it operational?
sample output need to happen but not happening
"Pls input an equation:"  --> 1+2 -->ans = 12

### here's my sample code...

```
def calculater(num1,operator,num2):
    if operator =="+":
        return  (num1 + num2)
    elif operator =="/":
        return (num1 / num2)
    elif operator =="*":
        return (num1 * num2)
    elif operator =="-":
        return(num1 - num2)

equations = input("Enter equation:")
final = calculater(equations[0],str(equations[1]),equations[2])
print(final)
```

Comment: When you call the `input` function in python, it returns a string. You can use the `int` function to convert it to a number.

Comment: Use this final = calculater( int(equations[0]),str(equations[1]),int(equations[2])) to instead. And it works.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is wrong.

1. you are concatenating the strings, you are not adding them as an `int`
2. even if you convert them to int and add them Since you are referring to the numbers and the operator using index so your logic only works for adding single-digit numbers. If you do sth like `12+5`, you will get this error.

```py
Enter equation:12+5
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 12, in <module>
    final = calculater(int(equations[0]),str(equations[1]),int(equations[2]))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '+'
```

This is happening because python expects the third index to be int since you are passing that in your function. There are different workarounds for this, but if you just want to calculate you can use built-in function `eval()` like this.

```py
equations = input("Enter equation:")
final = eval(equations)
print(final)
```

Comment: yeah, i was only testing 3 digit charaters only, I know there would be an eror if 2 or more digits before the operator is inputed or the 2nd number.

Comment: @BhorgeTV Ok, what did you want to know? or did you already found your answer